# In a UITableView, best method to cancel GCD operations for cells that have gone off screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have a `UITableView` that loads images from a URL into cells asynchronously using GCD. Problem is if a user flicks past 150 rows, 150 operations queue up and execute. What I want is to dequeue/cancel the ones that blew past and went off screen.

How do I do this?

My code at this point (pretty standard):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    // after getting the cell...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        if (runQ) {
            NSString *galleryTinyImageUrl = [[self.smapi getImageUrls:imageId imageKey:imageKey] objectForKey:@"TinyURL"];
            NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:galleryTinyImageUrl]];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (imageData != nil) {
                    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

runQ is a `BOOL` ivar I set to `NO` on `viewWillDisappear`, which (I think) has the effect of flushing out the queue rapidly when this `UITableView` pops off the navigation controller.

So, back to my original question: how do I cancel the image fetch operations for cells that have gone off screen? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, don't queue operations while scrolling. Instead, load images for just the visible rows in `viewDidLoad` and when the user stops scrolling:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]) {
        [self loadImageForCellAtPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

If you still want to be able to cancel loading for invisible cells, you could use `NSBlockOperation` instead of GCD:

```
self.operationQueue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount];

// ...

-(void)loadImageForCellAtPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    __block NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        if (![operation isCancelled]) {
            NSString *galleryTinyImageUrl = [[self.smapi getImageUrls:imageId imageKey:imageKey] objectForKey:@"TinyURL"];
            NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:galleryTinyImageUrl]];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (imageData != nil) {
                    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                }
            });
        }
    }];

    NSValue *nonRetainedOperation = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObjectValue:operation];
    [self.operations addObject:nonRetainedOperation forKey:indexPath];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Here `operations` is an `NSMutableDictionary`. When you want to cancel an operation, you retrieve it by the cell's `indexPath`, cancel it, and remove it from the dictionary:

```
NSValue *operationHolder = [self.operations objectForKey:indexPath];
NSOperation *operation = [operationHolder nonretainedObjectValue];
[operation cancel];
```

Comment: I need to call the cancel part (your second code snippet) when a cell exits the view. The only method I know of that gets invoked on this event is the cell object's `prepreForReuse`, whose scope has no access to the object `[self.operations]` (or its `indexPath`). Am I right? Thanks, this is great.

Comment: What about grabbing `[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]` and then iterate over `self.operations` and cancel all operations that aren't in the array of indexPaths? You could do that in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, and perhaps `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: I tried this approach and noticed the app slowing down dramatically. When adding the operation, should we be adding to something other than mainQueue?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cancel GCD operations after they've been dispatched. You can however check in the dispatch blocks to see if the code needs to continue on or not. In -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: you can do something like this

```
UIImage *image = [imageCache objectForKey:imageName];
if(image) {
    cell.imageView.image = image;
else {
    dispatch_async(globalQueue, ^{
        //get your image here...
        UIImage *image = ...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if([cell.indexPath isEqual:indexPath){
                cell.indexPath = nil;
                cell.imageView.image = image;
                [cell setNeedsLayout];
            }
        });
        [imageCache setObject:image forKey:imageName];
    });
}
```

Basically use a image cache (NSMutableDictionary) and try to grab the image. If you don't have it then dispatch a block and get it. Then dispatch back to the main thread, check the index path and then set the image and finally cache the image. This example uses a custom tableview cell that has the index path stored with it as a property.

So its a little extra work, to make this work well, but its worth it.

Comment: While this prevents you from reloading an image you already have, it doesn't address @Steven's original problem, which is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called as you're scrolling past cells you're might not look at. But you make a good point that he should be caching the images. Depending on the domain, might be even better to write the cache to disk.

Comment: FYI, I do cache . Just omitted it for clarity sake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dequeued cells the best approach is to cancel GCD in

-[UITableViewCell prepareForReuse]

Comment: What is the call to cancel GCD? If you could provide code snippet I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: mmm, my bad, you can't cancel block execution once it've been dispatched on queue. You should consider creating class (e.g. ImageFetcher) which will use ASYNCHRONOUS connection, so you can send cancel message.