# Threads are killing my app

Tags: objective-c, ios

Looking for some advice on stablizing my app. First some requirements - files with PII (personally identifying information) must be encrypted when on disk. Tumbnails and logos are in the custom TableViewCells (if available) and must be decrypted before display.

There are several layers of threading going on. There is a central function getFileData that checks to see if files are on the device or if the files need to be obtained from the network.  I desire to keep the UI responsive and (I think) therein lies my problem.

**Here is some code:**
This is the workhorse method for processing files in my application. It decides where the file is decrypts it and hands it back to a callback:

```
    -(void)fetchFileData:(UserSession *) session
              onComplete: (void(^)(NSData* data)) onComplete 
{
    NSURL *url = [File urlForMail:self.fileId andSession:session];
    //NSLog(@"File id: %@", self.fileId);
    NSString *encryptionKey = session.encryptionKey;
    dispatch_queue_t cryptoQ = dispatch_queue_create(FILE_CRYPTOGRAPHY_QUEUE, NULL);

    dispatch_async(cryptoQ, ^(void){
        // Get the file and d/encrypt it
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([File fileExistsAtUrl:url] == YES) { 
            NSLog(@"file is on disk.");
            NSData *localEncryptedFile = [File getDataForFile:url];
            NSData *decryptedFile = [RNDecryptor decryptData:localEncryptedFile 
                                                withPassword:encryptionKey 
                                                       error:&error];
            onComplete(decryptedFile);
            dispatch_release(cryptoQ);
        } else { 
            //NSLog(@"File is not on disk");
            NSDictionary *remoteFile = [session.apiFetcher getFileContent:self.fileId 
                                                                 andToken:session.token];
            if (remoteFile && [[remoteFile objectForKey:@"success"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {                
                NSData *remoteFileData = [remoteFile objectForKey:@"data"];
                NSString *mimeType = [remoteFile objectForKey:@"mimeType"];
                self.mimeType = mimeType;
                NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:remoteFileData 
                                                    withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings 
                                                        password:encryptionKey 
                                                           error:&error];
                [encryptedData writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
                onComplete(remoteFileData);
                dispatch_release(cryptoQ);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is an example of a getFileData caller:

```
    +(void)loadThumbnailForMail: (NSNumber*)thumbnailId 
                    session: (UserSession*)session 
                   callback: (void(^)(NSData* data))callback
{
    File *file = [File findFile:thumbnailId inContext:session.mailDatabase.managedObjectContext];    
    dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create(FILE_FETCHER_QUEUE_LABEL, NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^(void) { 
        if (file) {
            [file fetchFileData:session onComplete:^(NSData *data) {
                if (data && file.mimeType) {
                    callback(data);
                }
            }];
        }        
    });    
    dispatch_release(fetchQ);    
}
```

Here is an example of the TableViewCell that is calling loadThumbnailForMail:

```
    -(void)loadAndShowThumbnailImage:(Mail*) mail
{
    UIImage *placeHolder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbnail_placeholder.png"];
    [self.thumbnailImageForMail setImage:placeHolder];
    dispatch_queue_t loaderQ = dispatch_queue_create(THUMBNAIL_FETCHER, NULL);
    dispatch_async(loaderQ, ^ {
        [File loadThumbnailForMail: mail.thumbnailId 
                           session: [UserSession instance] 
                          callback: ^(NSData *data) {
                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                  UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                                  [self.thumbnailImageForMail setImage:thumbnailImage];
                              });
                      }];
    });
    dispatch_release(loaderQ);
}
```

I think that my issue here is the callback in my loadThumbnailImage. If the user scrolls fast enough I suspect that there could be two threads trying to access the same TableViewCell

```
(MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];)
```

It doesn't always happen right away but eventually, after some scrolling the tableView list of cells the app crashes with this: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0xde6a650> was mutated while being enumerated.'

I need to have the decrypted images in the cells and the first solution (above) does this for me when the images are available but causes the app to crash. I am wondering if some sort of in memory cache would help improve this if I put images in memory there when they were decrypted and checked that cache in loadAndShowThumbnailImage before I kick off all the threads to get and decrypt them.

Thoughts? I have been banging on this for a week now trying different things and would appreciate some fresh perspective.

Thanks.

Comment: As the message says, you can't mutate a set (or array/dictionary) while it's being enumerated... this can happen when a background thread is mutating a set that your foreground thread is iterating over. Can you pass a copy of your relevant data structure to your background thread?

Comment: The background threads are only working on NSData objects (Unless there is something else going on in the [link]https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor library I am using. I haven't looked at it too deep yet, only enough to make sure it really is secure enought for my requirements. I am thinking that the array/dictionary being enumerated on is in the main thread and the only object there to iterate on is a property of the managed object I am calling File: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *mails;

Comment: There must be a shared set for this error to pop up. I've hit this myself. Dig deeper and see if you can find the shared object.

Comment: on implementing background loading operations for table view cells: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930687/reusing-uitableviewcell-with-gcd/11931493#11931493

Comment: So are any of `Mail`, `File`, or `UserSession` `NSManagedObject` subclasses then? What are you doing to maintain thread safety there?

Comment: Actually reviewing where the NSSet property comes from, its a different class, something called MailFolder and it Is a subclass of NSManagedObject. It is used in some categories for the project. @nielsbot, any suggestions for digging deeper to identify the Set that is generating the NSGenericException? I tried adding a breakpoint for objc_exception_throw with a debugger command of bt but  I still didn't understand what (or where) the issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Justins link and subsequent research I ended up going in this direction: [In a UITableView, best method to cancel GCD operations for cells that have gone off screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408611/in-a-uitableview-best-method-to-cancel-gcd-operations-for-cells-that-have-gone)